# Problem regarding divisibility and GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

If $m>n$, prove that $a^{2^n}+1$ is a divisor of $a^{2^m}-1$. Find $(a^{2^n}+1, a^{2^m}+1)$, when $a,m,n$ are positive and $m\neq n$.

I TRY LIKE THIS:

Since $m>n$, $m=n+k$,
$$a^{2^m}-1=a^{2^n\cdot 2^k}-1$$
$$=(a^{2^n})^{2^k}-1$$
here I stops and can't able to proceed further. Please give me a hint and not answer. THANKS

Comment: Try first the case $m=n+1$

Comment: It is divisible by $a^{2^n}+1$!@Del

Comment: Can I use induction?

Comment: Sure! How would you proceed?

Comment: Assuming$$=(a^{2^n})^{2^k}-1$$ is true,$$(a^{2^n})^{2^{k+1}}-1=(a^{2^n})^{{2^k}.2}$$$$={a^{2^n}}^{2^k}.{a^{2^n}}^{2}-1+(a^{2^n})^{2}-{a^{2^n}}^{2}$$...continue

Comment: $(a^{2^n})^{2}((a^{2^n})^{2k}-1)+(a^{2^n})^{2}-1$,which is divisible by $a^{2^n}-1$.hence we prove it.am I right sir?sorry for late reply . I'm begginer in LaTeX so it takes time for me to type.@Del

Comment: How can I find the second result any hint or answer please

Answer (score 2):

We can write $k=m-n$, then note that $$a^{2^m}-1 = (a^{2^{n}2^{k-1}}+1)(a^{2^{n}2^{k-1}}-1).$$ If $k=1$, we have the result. If not, write $$(a^{2^{n}2^{k-1}}-1) = (a^{2^{n}2^{k-2}}-1)(a^{2^{n}2^{k-2}}+1)$$ if $k=2$, we have the result, if else repeat the process. Since $k$ is finite, in a finite number of steps we will have $$(a^{2^m}-1) = (a^{2^{n}}-1)(a^{2^{n}}+1)(a^{2^{n}2^1}+1)(a^{2^{n}2^{2}}+1)\cdots(a^{2^{n}2^{k-1}}+1)$$ and hence the result.